# LLVM ICmpInst produce broken instruction 'badref'?

Tags: llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I write the code below in a LLVM pass:

```
// context is retrieved from another valid instruction
Value *a = ConstantInt::get(IntegerType::get(context, 64), 1);
Value *b = ConstantInt::get(IntegerType::get(context, 64), 2);

Instruction *icmp = new ICmpInst(ICmpInst::ICMP_EQ, a, b);

icmp->print(errs());
```

The output is like below:

```
<badref> = icmp eq i64 1, 2
```

Any reason why we have this "badref" in the output here?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but my guess is that this is because you have not inserted the instructions into any basic block, and thus, llvm does not know what name to give the instruction.

Comment: oh, what can be the fix now?

Comment: Well, you can try inserting the instruction into a basic block.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly why you are receiving a `badref`; I tried calling `Builder.Insert(icmp)` but the `badref` was still present. You can use `Builder.CreateICmpEQ` as in the full example below to accomplish the same task.

```
#include "llvm/ADT/APInt.h"
#include "llvm/IR/BasicBlock.h"
#include "llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
#include <memory>

using namespace llvm;

static LLVMContext TheContext;
static IRBuilder<> Builder(TheContext);

int main() {
  static std::unique_ptr<Module> TheModule =
      std::make_unique<Module>("example.cpp", TheContext);

  FunctionType *mainType = FunctionType::get(Builder.getInt32Ty(), false);
  Function *main = Function::Create(mainType, Function::ExternalLinkage, "main",
                                    TheModule.get());

  BasicBlock *entry = BasicBlock::Create(TheContext, "entry", main);
  Builder.SetInsertPoint(entry);
  Value *a = ConstantInt::get(IntegerType::get(TheContext, 64), 1);
  Value *b = ConstantInt::get(IntegerType::get(TheContext, 64), 2);
  auto ret = Builder.CreateICmpEQ(a, b);
  /*return value for `main`*/
  Builder.CreateRet(ret);
  /*Emit the LLVM IR to the console*/
  TheModule->print(outs(), nullptr);
}
```